# Who waits for a shell background process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, wait

I was wondering about this question:

If I type the following command in bash

# sleep 100 &

How come the shell knows to wait for it to end?

When the shell forks itself in order to exec the sleep command, doesn't the ampersand technically means it's not going to wait for that newly forked process?
Nevertheless, it still waits for it (otherwise I would've seen it as a zombie, and I don't)

Feeling confused here :\

Comment: Because it keeps a list of running jobs.

Comment: Don't really understand what it means..
How is it different?

Comment: When you go pick up your kids from school, what keeps you from driving up to the school, waiting 15 seconds, and then driving away? **The fact that you know how many children you have, and how many haven't entered the car yet.**

Comment: Also, not all forms of the `wait()` call block. The shell can poll for whether it has any children which have finished running while it's doing its print-a-prompt business, reap them if they're done, and proceed without delaying otherwise.

Comment: Of course it does, eventually. It doesn't perform a *blocking* wait, though, and that's the important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell gets a `SIGCHLD` when its child process exits; thus, it can immediately call `wait4()` in the signal handler to reap it.

If you run `strace bash`, you'll see something like the following:

```
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13708, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 13708
wait4(-1, 0x7fffbca63110, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

That is to say: The shell gets a signal that a child process exited; it calls `wait4()` without a PID, thus reaping the first dead child from its process table; and calls that again, and is informed that no dead children remain to be reaped.

This differs from the case where a process is run in the foreground, where a *blocking* `wait()` is run immediately.

Comment: it reads like a horror movie...